# Almost sure equivalence of regular conditonal probability of a progressive process in a controlled SDE equation.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the (canonical path) space of continuous functions $\Omega = C([0,T],\mathbb{R})$ with the Borel-sigma algebra generated by the open sets induced by the uniform topology and $\mathbb{P}$ Wiener Measure on it (and canonical process $B_t(\omega) = \omega(t))$. 
Working through the paper "Julien Claisse, Denis Talay, Xiaolu Tan:  A pseudo-Markov property for controlled diffusion processes" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03939) i am stuck understanding a identity of the regular conditional probability when having a diffusion SDE (to be more precise Page 6, Equation 10): 
Say we have a solution
\begin{equation}
X_T^{t,x,u} = x_t + \int_{t}^{T} \mu(z,{X}_z^{t,x,u}, u_z) dz + \int_{t}^{T} \sigma(z,{X}_z^{t,x,u},u_z) dB_z 
\end{equation}
Then it also holds for $ t \leq s    \leq T$ by writing out (and using continuity)
\begin{equation}
X_T^{t,x,u} = X_s^{t,x,u} + \int_{s}^{T} \mu(z,{X}_z^{t,x,u}, u_z) dz + \int_{s}^{T} \sigma(z,{X}_z^{t,x,u},u_z) dB_z 
\end{equation}
Assume there exists a regular conditional probability $(\mathbb{P}_\omega)_{w \in \Omega}$ for $\mathcal{F}_T:= \bigvee_{0 \leq t\leq T } \mathcal{F}_t$ given $\mathcal{F}_s$ for $ t \leq s \leq T$. Then it holds for the stopped process $[{X}^{t,x,u}]_s := (X_{s \wedge z}^{t,x,v})_{0 \leq z \leq T} $

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}_{\omega} \left( [{X}^{t,x,u}]_s = [{X}^{t,x,u}]_s(\omega) \right) = 1 \qquad  for \quad \mathbb{P} \quad a.all \quad \omega \in \Omega
\end{equation}
(see also Lemma 3.2 in the referenced paper). 
However why is it true that it also holds for the progressive process $u_t$ and the concatenation process $(u_z^{t,\omega})_{0 \leq z \leq T }$ defined by
\begin{equation}
u_z^{t,\omega}( \bar{\omega}) := 
\{
\begin{array}{ll}
u_z ( \omega(y) ), \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad if \quad 0 \leq y \leq t  \\
u_z( \omega(t) + \bar{\omega}(y) - \bar{\omega} (t)) , \quad if \quad t \leq y \leq T\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}_{\omega} ( u = u^{s,\omega}) = 1 \qquad  for \quad \mathbb{P} \quad a.all \quad \omega \in \Omega \qquad ? 
\end{equation}
Especially i am wondering of how to particularly derive the form of the additional concatenation of the above process. Can anyone light this maybe up? Probably i am missing a property of a representation of processes measurable to the sigma algebra generated by the brownian motion in this setting.

Comment: Might be eligible for mathoverflow IMO : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/stochastic-processes

Comment: I will wait a day (or two) more but then will consider MO, ty for your comment @TheBridge . I tried a lot around the easy "trick" of adding a zero in the control process to make use of independent increments of the canonical process and calculate around with properties of the r.c.p but really cant derive it... this relation seems so close and still so far away to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it: 
Like expected it is more about basic properties of the Brownian Motion (without sigma algebra...) which yields above relation while the SDE equation's can be forgotten: 
For a fix $t \in [0,T]$ it follows from a classical result about the r.c.p ( Karatzas/Shreve: Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus page 307 Theorem 3.18) that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}^{\omega} ( u_t = u_t (\omega) ) =1 \quad for \quad  \mathbb{P} \quad a.all \quad  \omega \in \Omega 
\end{equation}
(it is also used in my question post for the stopped path process). 
Now consider the "Shifted to t Brownian Motion" (we know that this process again is a $ \mathbb{P} $ BM by standard estimates, or any literature about BM).
\begin{equation}
B^{\bigtriangleup t}_{(\cdot)}:= B_{t+ ( \cdot )} - B_t 
\end{equation}
and the shifting operator process $\theta _t$ on $C([0,T], \mathbb{R}$ ):
\begin{equation}
(\theta_t B )_s = := 
\{
\begin{array}{ll}
B_{s-t} , \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \qquad \qquad if \quad 0 \leq t \leq s  \\
0 , \quad \quad \quad \quad \qquad \qquad \qquad  if \quad  0\leq s \leq t\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

It holds now (crucial equality here)
\begin{equation}
B = [B]_t + \theta_t \cdot  B^{\bigtriangleup t} \qquad \mathbb{P} -a.s
\end{equation}
which gives above additive concatenation. 
Then we can define above concatenation process function taking the  $B^{ \bigtriangleup t }$ as input (or any other Brownian Motion independent from $\mathcal{F}_t$, like done in above concatenation process) to still have $\mathbb{P} $ equality.
From the properties of the regular conditional probability, it is pathwise equal to the $\mathbb{P}$ path, indeed above equation holds $ \mathbb{P}^{\omega} $ a.s. from which the claimed equality now follows.